# How should the database be for a one to one chat application in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is my current database structure which isn't working and I've learnt that its not the right way to achieve what I want...

```
{
"Messages" : {
"+918105571584" : {
  "+919945342730" : {
    "-L5AFX_RMebwd3EiuWUm" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518459824840,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L5AFah6msuwW2fCXnMg" : {
      "message" : "Hey",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518459841703,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L5AFbmLTctRBxXjAkDW" : {
      "message" : "Message",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518459846120,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
},
"+919945342730" : {
  "+918105571584" : {
    "-L5AFX_RMebwd3EiuWUm" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518459824840,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L5AFah6msuwW2fCXnMg" : {
      "message" : "Hey",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518459841703,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L5AFbmLTctRBxXjAkDW" : {
      "message" : "Message",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1518459846120,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
}
},
"Users" : {
"+918105571584" : {
  "Email" : "",
  "Name" : "Akash",
  "Quote" : "",
  "Status" : ""
},
"+919945342730" : {
  "Email" : "",
  "Name" : "Sav",
  "Quote" : "",
  "Status" : ""
}
}
}
```

First a child messages and inside that senders id(phone number) receivers id(phone number) and then unique id which contains message... so if this is not the right way to achieve one to one chat application can someone tel me how my database structure should be to achieve that

Chat Activity

```
public class Chat extends AppCompatActivity {


Button addImage;
Button sendButton;
EditText messageArea;
ScrollView scrollView;
TextView name;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String MessageSenderId;
String MessageRecieverId;
DatabaseReference rootRef;
RecyclerView userMessageList;
private final List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
FirebaseUser user;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_message);
    messageArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_message);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    addImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_image);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    name.setText((getIntent().getStringExtra("name")));

    messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);
    userMessageList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.messageList);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    userMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    userMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    userMessageList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);


    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    user  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
    MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("visit_user_id");




    fetchMessages();


    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void fetchMessages() {
    rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                    messagesList.add(messages);
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {



                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });

}

private void sendMessage() {
 String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText)){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't Send Blank Message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
     String message_sender_ref = "Messages/" + MessageSenderId + "/" + MessageRecieverId;
     String message_reciver_ref = "Messages/" + MessageRecieverId + "/" + MessageSenderId;

     DatabaseReference user_message_key = rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId)
                                                 .child(MessageRecieverId).push();
     String message_push_id = user_message_key.getKey();

     Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
     messageTextBody.put("number",MessageSenderId);
     messageTextBody.put("message",messageText);
     messageTextBody.put("seen",false);
     messageTextBody.put("type","text");
     messageTextBody.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);



     Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();

     messageBodyDetails.put(message_sender_ref + "/" + message_push_id,messageTextBody);
     messageBodyDetails.put(message_reciver_ref + "/" + message_push_id,messageTextBody);

     rootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
             if (databaseError != null){
                 Log.d("Chat_Log", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
             }
             messageArea.setText("");
         }
     });

 }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Messages
        uniqueid
           number:"+918105571584"
           "message" : "Hi",
           "seen" : false,
           "time" : 1518459824840,
           "type" : "text"
        uniqueid
            number: "+919945342730"
             "message" : "Hey",
             "seen" : false,
             "time" : 1518459841703,
             "type" : "text"
```

etc..

Keep the `Users` node also.

Try the above, the user with the first number, sends a message to the user with the second number. After sending the message this data will appear in your database:

```
    uniqueid
        number:"+918105571584"
       "message" : "Hi",
       "seen" : false,
       "time" : 1518459824840,
       "type" : "text"
```

When the other user sees the message, you can then update `seen` to true.

Then the second user sends a message, and his data also will appear in the database.

```
     uniqueid
            number: "+919945342730"
             "message" : "Hey",
             "seen" : false,
             "time" : 1518459841703,
             "type" : "text"
```

---

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").push();
ref.child("number").setValue(anumberhere);
ref.child("message").setValue(messagehere);
ref.child("seen").setValue(false);
....
```

Comment: like the senders id in both the messages is showing the same id... y is that... where hav i gone wrong

Comment: Map messageTextBody = new HashMap<>();
         messageTextBody.put("number",MessageSenderId);
         messageTextBody.put("message",messageText);
         messageTextBody.put("seen",false);
         messageTextBody.put("type","text");
         messageTextBody.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

Comment: But i have no code like that in my activity... see my edits plz,,, please bare with me juz a beginner here

Comment: @CourtneyMiller change this 
     DatabaseReference user_message_key = rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId)
                                                 .child(MessageRecieverId).push(); to this  DatabaseReference user_message_key = rootRef.child("Messages").push()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165176/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-courtney-miller).